# Redefining unsigned Char Boolean_type to True and false struct

Tags: c, misra, autosar

According to Autosar_SWS the boolean must be `unsigned char`. 
But I am having lots of MISRA violation in my compositions, like MISRA rule 10.1 (conversion violation), Rule 12.6 (effective boolean).

I would like to know if I redefine the BOOLEAN for my application like below:

```
#ifdefine BOOLEAN_T
#undefine BOOLEAN_T

typedef struct {
                 unsigned char TRUE  : 1;
                 unsigned char FALSE : 1;
               } BOOLEAN_T;    

#define TRUE 1;
#define False 0;

#endif
```

What will be the safety concerns and the consequences?

Comment: What is the purpose of defining BOOLEAN_T as a struct, rather than as unsigned char?

Comment: Well its functional safety software . I would like to strict the boolean value to 0,1 .. not to 0 and non-zero. and avoid any misra violations

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For safety you can use for example a bit pattern:

```
unsigned char data = 0x55 << (input_bit & 1);

switch (data):/* instead of if() */
 case 0xaa:
  /*true*/
  break;
 case 0x55:
  /*false*/
  break;
 case default:
  /*exception*/
  break;
}
```

Comment: It would make a lot more sense to use an error correcting code to protect the data value against random bit flips. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error-correcting_code

Comment: It is usually true but if you don't have hardware ECC a software ECC/CRC is effective (speed of code) for data blocks - not for a single variable.

Comment: thanks    .. my question not to stick to 1 bit. but more to strict to 0 and 1


    #ifdefine BOOLEAN_T
    #undefine BOOLEAN_T
    
    typedef struct {
                     unsigned char TRUE  ;
                     unsigned char FALSE ;
                   } BOOLEAN_T;    
    
    #define TRUE 1;
    #define False 0;
    
    #endif

Comment: @nopsoft: ECC can be easily implemented in software. An ECC code can be defined to protect a value of any size B bits from N errors for any values of B and N.

Comment: It is possible but let's notice code overhead for a single variable. It depends on your application. FEC is usually implemented in hardware (eg. DVBT).

Comment: Anyways thanks guys for the quick answers!! . There were too many different ways of defining the Boolean type in common usage, and no generally accepted single definition. Even MISRA-2004 don't have any clear definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a 2 bit struct to represent a single bit quantity, a random bit flip has a 50% chance of changing the true/false value to a value that is neither true nor false.

*Please* spend some more time studying the C language before attempting to write safety critical software.

Comment: A **single** random bit flip has a 100% chance of changing a valid content to neither true nor false. Making a single bitflip detectable that way could be considered a feature... But if starting something like that, an ECC would be even more useful.

Answer (score 1):

By your above method,there is a possibility of MISRA Warnings for using bifields over unsigned char.

I would suggest you to leave the definition of boolean to the platform guys of AUTOSAR (platform types) and concentrate on using boolean as an `unsigned char`.